# conditional statement in loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++){
    for (b = 1; b <= i; b++){
        cout << "X";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

if a=4, the result would be

```
X

XX

XXX

XXXX
```

while the output of this

```
for (i = 1; i <= a; i++){
    for (b = 1; b <= a - i; b++){
        cout << "A";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

will be

```
AAA

AA

A
```

i recognize the different in conditional statement but i can not explain it my self why so.

Comment: Step through this code in a debugger if you can't work through what it does on paper. You also need to adopt a consistent indentation style because what you have here is pure chaos and very hard to read.

Comment: Write it out on paper. i will be 1, for 1 .. (4-1). i is 2, for 1..(4-2)...

Comment: Assume `a` is `4` like you said. The first iteration of the second loop would iterate for `a-i` times, which would be `1 < 4-0`. Sometimes just writing this out with some pen and paper can do wonders.

Comment: i wrote it down and spent 3 hours before asking here. none answer the question but i assume that the value in conditional statement of loop is the number of loops(?). for i = 1.. (4-1)would be 3,i =2 (4-2)would be 2..
but why in first loop its not work like that for i =1.. 4(?) ... this i don't understand. how conditional statement works in for loop

Answer (score 0):

For your first example, the first for loop with run because 1 is less than a (4). Which then it will move on to the next for loop. So b = 1, and 1 equals to 1 which will run and print out X. Now that loop will end and the outer for loop will increment to 2, and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your stop conditions for the inner loops:

```
b <= i;
b <= a - i;
```

Now, let's start with `i` being 1:

```
b <= 1;
b <= 3;
```

And, finish with `i` being 4:

```
b <= 4;
b <= 0;
```

Considering your `b`'s initializations:

```
b = 1;
b = 1;
```

Combine them all => your loop ranges for `b`s would be `[1; 4]` and `[3; 1]`.